# Data parametrization in cucumber with different data in same step definition

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, ui-automation, testng-dataprovider

I have query regarding data parameterization in Cucumber framework that I am working currently.
scenario is I login to retail e commerce app and search for 5 different products and add to cart, proceed to payment page.

Issue: How can we write logic or scenario steps to add 5 products and procced to payment screen working with cucumber?

```
Given I login to retail App
When I enter <username> and <password>
And I click on login button 
Then I land on home page
And I search <Product> and add it to cart
And I Proceed to Payment page

Example:
|username| |password| |Product|
|user1| |pwd1| |p1,p2,p3,p4,p5|
```

My thought :  Can we write a reusable logic by iterating the product parameter values in step definition method where I get the Product value from example and split it with ",".

Is there a better way to re run single scenario step with multiple data? if so please guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: You can try with cucumber data tables here as defined like https://www.toolsqa.com/cucumber/data-tables-in-cucumber/

Comment: Yes, you can split the string with `,` and do that. But I suggest you to use excel because in future when you write all of your data in feature files, it will be tough to maintain.